# format sagetex code like console or notebook

Tags: sagetex

I'd like to put sage code in my LaTeX document that looks mostly like how an interactive session would appear, except that I want LaTeX formatted output.

So, I'd like to write something like this in my LaTeX file:

```
\begin{sageblock}
gcd(x^2 + 2*x + 1, x + 1)
\end{sageblock}
```

and the result is first a Courier-typeset box containing

```
sage: gcd(x^2 + 2*x + 1, x + 1)
```

and then a box after that containing the LaTeX formatted result.

```
$$ x+1 $$
```

Any idea how to do this, without assigning the result to an auxiliary variable and then printing the variable?

Answer (score 2):

### The `sageexample` environment

The `sageexample` environment does exactly that (except the `sage:` prompt needs to be added by hand).

Create a latex file `gcd.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sageexample}
sage: gcd(x^2 + 2*x + 1, x + 1)
\end{sageexample}
\end{document}​
```

then in a terminal run

```
pdflatex gcd && sage gcd.sagetex.sage && pdflatex gcd
```

and a pdf will be produced containing

> ```
> sage : gcd(x^2 + 2*x + 1, x + 1)
> ```
>
> x + 1

(where x + 1 is typeset).

### The `sagecommandline` environment

Note the related `sagecommandline` environment
which leaves the output in non-typeset form,
and is good for running doctests.

Create a latex file `gcd.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagecommandline}
sage: gcd(x^2 + 2*x + 1, x + 1)
\end{sagecommandline}
\end{document}​
```

then in a terminal run

```
pdflatex gcd && sage gcd.sagetex.sage && pdflatex gcd
```

and a pdf will be produced containing

```
sage : gcd(x^2 + 2*x + 1, x + 1)
x + 1
```

with additional line numbering. To remove the line numbering,
add the line

```
\lstdefinestyle{SageInput}{style=DefaultSageInput,numbers=none}
```

somewhere before `\begin{sagecommandline}`.

Comment: Nah,instead of getting a PDF with the desired output,I get one with ?? Instead of sage code. What should I do?

Comment: @Shreya what output do you get for `sage --version`, and have you installed SageTeX? See http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html

Comment: its version 8.8 and yes I have sagetex installed.

Comment: @Shreya what happens whey you run `sage` on the `.sagetex.sage` file?